# Calling plugins method from Datepicker

Tags: jquery, plugins, methods

I try to create a basic jQuery Plugin and I'm stucked and try to understand how do I call plugin method from inside of my Datepicker instance on onSelect event. When I try to call this.updateWidgate() fails.

```
        init: function() {
            var dateToday = new Date();
            var arrival_date = '';
            var departure_date = '';
            $element = $(this.element);

            var lang = this.getParameterByName('lang');
            if (lang !== '') {
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[lang]);
            } else {
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);
            }

            var arrival = $element.find('#arrival').find('.calendar').datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    arrival = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //the getDate method
                    console.log(arrival);
                    this.updateWidget(); //here I try to call method
                }
            });
            var departure = $element.find('#departure').find('.calendar').datepicker();
            //arrival.hide();
            departure.hide();
            this.initWidget();
        },

updateWidget: function() {
            alert();
        },
```

**Update**
I got it working but not sure if is the appropriate approach with

`var self = this;` in my init function